# Classicthesis in Chinese?

Tags: lyx, languages, babel, cjk, classicthesis

I wish to compile my dissertation in the beautiful `classicthesis`.
My setting: Mac OX 10.6.8, TeX Live 2012 + LyX 2.0.5.
I am able to work and produce document in Chinese elsewhere including in `book`, `memoir`, but just not in `classicthesis`.
After several attempts, including copying following solution...
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=11098
Maybe the problem is on `babel`  that doesn't accommodate Chinese?
I wonder if anyone can provide a direction for solving this issue.

Comment: `\usepackage{ctex}`, then it can produce Chinese words. Why not use `pkuthss`,`seuthesis` or `thuthesis`? They are all thesis templates for Chinese.

Comment: Thank you for the kind suggestion, Pig Cry. I got the problem solved. It didn't go with \usepackage{ctex}, but with {pinyin}{babel}.

Comment: @user24219 I'm interested in using classicthesis, and I also use Chinese text; would you mind writing out the full solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

step 1: find `-config.tex` and make following change. `{latin9}{inputenc}`↔`{utf8}{inputenc}`. `{ngerman,american}{babel}`↔`{pinyin,american}{babel}`. plus adding `\usepackage[pinyin]{babel}`. 
step 2: go to each document and perform lyx document setting→fonts/cjk/bsmi(or others). then →language: chinese(...), encoding: language default. modules should be selected accordingly.